# Check if any date within a range is within 1 month of todays date

Tags: excel

I've got a column full of dates.  How can I check that column to find which date is within a month of todays date, and then return it?

If there is no date within a month, just return blank

Lets say my dates are:

```
01-Jan-12   
01-Apr-12   
01-Jul-12   
01-Oct-12   
01-Jan-13
```

The code im using is below. A:A is the range of the dates above

```
=MIN(IF(A:A>TODAY(),A:A))
```

The issue im having is that if I use the above, it returns 01/01/12 and not 01/01/13.  Also, if I change the dates so the next date is December 1st 2012, it still returns 01/01/12

Comment: When you say "within a month" do you mean in the past or the future or possibly both? Are your dates restricted to past or future dates? Also are the dates in any particular order?

Comment: K20GH, please be aware that this isn't a coding facility for users but a forum for programmers to get help with their existing codes or a hint for direction. So I will give just that: press the fx button in Excel and go to the date and time category or play around with the cell format and change it into number for a change for those dates

Comment: @barryhoudini All dates are in the future only.  I thought I could do it with lookup but I dont think I can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you really just want the earliest date if that's within a month? If so perhaps try

`=IF(MIN(A:A)-TODAY()<=30,MIN(A:A),"")`

Assumes dates in column A

If you have past and future dates try this formula

`=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(A2:A100>=TODAY(),IF(A2:A100<=TODAY()+30,A2:A100)),1),"")`

confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

or for exactly 1 month (rather than 30 days) try using EDATE, i.e.

`=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(A2:A100>=TODAY(),IF(A2:A100<=EDATE(TODAY(),1),A2:A100)),1),"")`

Comment: Basically I've got a list of dates, and I want a cell to only populate if todays date is within one month of a future date.  For instance, if 01/01/13 is the next future date in the list, the result would be blank until 01/12/12.   It appears your code will only give the result of 01/01/12 regardless of content

Comment: You should look at conditional formatting.  That will allow you to show or hide the date in each cell based on the condition you specified.

Comment: Is 01/01/12 in the list? I thought all dates were in the future?

Comment: Oh silly me.  Sorry, all dates won't be in the future depending on the time of year.  So some dates will be in the past and some will be in the future.  I just need to it return the next future date in the list

Comment: OK, I edited my suggestion to include an "array formula" to get you the earliest date between today and today +30.....if such a date exists, I assume you are using Excel 2007 or later?

Comment: instead of today() + 30 you should use date(year(today()), month(today()) + 1, day(today()))

Comment: Yes I'm using Excel 2010.  The forumula provided gives 01/01/1900, little bit confused as to why though

Comment: Are you using exactly that formula (with IFERROR and SMALL)? Have you confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER? (if so you'll see curly braces like { and } around formula)

Comment: @Dan, yes that's another approach but if today is 31st jan 2013 that will give 3rd March 2013 so I'd suggest using EDATE, see my edit.......

Comment: Briliant, got it working.  I didn't realise I needed to hit ctrl-alt-enter.  Whats the difference?

Comment: "array formulas" use functions that normally would apply to single cells to whole ranges - CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER tells Excel to "iterate" through each cell in the range.....